# Change Weights in BNNS Convolution Layer

Tags: accelerate-framework

After calling `BNNSFilterCreateConvolutionLayer` (and passing in a `BNNSConvolutionLayerParameters`), is it possible to change the weights in the filter?
Right now I have:

```
BNNSConvolutionLayerParameters layer_params;
bzero(&layer_params, sizeof(layer_params));
layer_params.weights.data = ....
...
... = BNNSFilterCreateConvolutionLayer(..., &layer_params, ...)
```

but I would like to be able to change the buffer pointed to by `layer_params.weights.data` with having to destroy and re-create (`BNNSFilterCreateConvolutionLayer`) the `BNNSFilter`.